# How to use a directional light in a blinn shader instead of point light?

Tags: opengl, glsl, lighting

So I am using a blinn shader program on some of my models, that uses a DIRECTIONAL light as opposed to a point light. I started out this original code that uses a point light:

**VERTEX:**

```
varying vec3 Half;
varying vec3 Light;
varying vec3 Normal;
varying vec4 Ambient;

void main()
{
   // Vertex location in modelview coordinates
   vec3 P = vec3(gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex);
   Light  = vec3(gl_LightSource[0].position) - P;
   Normal = gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal;
   Half  = gl_LightSource[0].halfVector.xyz;
   Ambient = gl_FrontMaterial.emission + gl_FrontLightProduct[0].ambient + gl_LightModel.ambient*gl_FrontMaterial.ambient;
   gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
   gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

**FRAGMENT:**

```
varying vec3 Half;
varying vec3 Light;
varying vec3 Normal;
varying vec4 Ambient;
uniform sampler2D tex;

vec4 blinn()
{
   vec3 N = normalize(Normal);
   vec3 L = normalize(Light);
   vec4 color = Ambient;
   float Id = dot(L,N);
   if (Id>0.0)
   {
      color += Id*gl_FrontLightProduct[0].diffuse;
      vec3 H = normalize(Half);
      float Is = dot(H,L); // Specular is cosine of reflected and view vectors
      if (Is>0.0) color += pow(Is,gl_FrontMaterial.shininess)*gl_FrontLightProduct[0].specular;
   }
   return color;
}
void main()
{
   gl_FragColor = blinn() * texture2D(tex,gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
}
```

However, as stated above, instead of a point light I want I want a directional light, such that no matter where in the scene the model is the direction of the light is the same. So I make the following changes:

Instead of:

```
varying vec3 Light;
```

and

```
vec3 P = vec3(gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex);
Light  = vec3(gl_LightSource[0].position) - P;
```

I get rid of the above lines of code and instead in my fragment shader have:

```
uniform vec4 lightDir;
```

and

```
vec3 L = normalize(lightDir.xyz);
```

I pass the direction of the light as a uniform outside of a my shader program, and this works good: the model is lighted from a single direction no matter its location in the world! **HOWEVER**, now the lighting changes dramatically and unrealistically depending on the user's view, which makes sense since I got rid of ("-P ") in the light calculation in the original code. I've already tried adding that to the code (by moving lightDir back to vertex shader and passing it along again in a varying) to what I have and it just doesn't fix the problem. I'm afraid I just don't understand what is going well enough to figure this out, I understand that the " - P" for the Light vec3 is necessary: to make specular/reflection work, but I don't know how to make it work for a directional light. How do I make take the original above code, and make it so the light is treated as a directional light as opposed to a point light?

Comment: "which makes sense since I got rid of ("-P ")". Why does it make sense ? In the end you normalize the ray vector, whether it comes from a point or a directional light.

Comment: You use the halfway vector from gl_LightSource, I think that's where lies the problem. OpenGL doesn't know you're using a directional light. I've never used the Legacy so I don't know how you C code looks like. Can you define your light as a directional one ? If you can/do, I think OpenGL will compute the halfway vector properly (from the direction, not the position). If you can't, you will have to compute the halfway vector yourself, not take it from gl_LightSource.